# Google Sign-In "An error has ocurred. That's all we know" inside Instagram's webview

Tags: android, webview, instagram, google-signin

I have integrated the Sign In with Google for Web js API (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client) into my website.

Everything is working fine, except when the website is loaded inside a WebView in Instagram. In that case, when a user tries to log in and chooses an account, Google shows a webpage with the error "An error has occurred. That's all we know" (see pictures attached at the end).

I suspect that this problem occurs because of some WebView restrictions that Google imposes, preventing users from logging in with Google from WebViews.

To check this assumption, I created a simple Android app to load my website inside a WebView. What I found is that the Google script request (https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client) fails with HTTP status 403, and no additional information is given. Later, I found this in the [docs](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/12917337?hl=en#403disallowed):

> 403 disallowed_useragent
>
> If you get an error that says “403 disallowed_useragent,” the app uses
> embedded WebViews. Some developers use WebViews to help display web
> content in an app. Embedded WebViews put your security at risk
> because they could let third parties access and change communications
> between you and Google.
>
> To keep your account secure, Google no longer allows embedded WebViews
> as of September 30, 2021. What can you do about this error?
>
> Only the third-party developer can fix this issue on the app. Contact
> the developer directly to tell them about the error.
>
> If the app has a website, you can try to sign in from your browser.

It's strange that the Google button loads in Instagram's WebView but not in mine (even using the same User-Agent). I'm not sure if this is related to the error that is occurring in Instagram's WebView, but it might be.

I have no way of reproducing the error, nor do I have control over making Instagram open my website in the browser. What should I do or investigate next to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that Instagram isn't using Custom Tabs, rather than a webview?

Comment: @Private_GER I was not aware of Custom Tabs. How would I verify that? The scenario that I'm describing is when the user clicks on a link on a instagram profile. The website opens inside instagram's app. I have verified that the User Agent is Samsung's browser instead of my default browser (Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Messenger browser supports no more than 1 tab at a time. So if you use `signInWithPopup` it removes the main page and takes you to the auth provider page which later on can't figure how to go back to the previous page. Consider using `signInWithRedirect` instead.

It worked for me. Thanks you....

This will work in single tab browsers..

```
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```

And this one won't..

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your suggestion. I'm not using firebase as I'm integrating directly with google api. But I can confirm that I'm already using the redirect option as described in https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#ux_mode

Comment: Add some of code snippets, so only we will able to check where is the problem.